# Atom редактор - фон

Tags: редактор, atom, редактор-текста

Доброго времени суток. Кто нибудь знает как исправить такой странный фон на MAC в редакторе Atom. Выглядит так, будто выделение происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тему меняли? Какая сейчас стоит?

Comment: Тема стоит monokai